# Eclipse Luna -- Intellisense Went Away

Tags: eclipse

I know it's not called Intellisense but I don not know what it is called. When I enter an object name and press the 'dot' nothing pops up. I could memorize all the properties and methods of all the classes in Java but it's easier to ask for help here.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called **Content Assist** in Eclipse.

You can enable auto activation of content assist in the preferences under `Java > Editor > Content Assist`. Check the `Enable auto activation` checkbox and make sure there is a `.` in the `Auto activation triggers for Java:` textfield.

These settings should actually be the default, so you may press the `Restore Defaults` button instead.